# Grails 3.0.9 ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: grails

my `application.yml` >

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: root
    password: *****

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            #dbCreate: create-drop
            #url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            dbCreate: update
            driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username: "root"
            password: "*****"
```

In `build.gradle` >

```
dependencies {
                runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
```

Exception >

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

even I tried running from command prompt..
giving same `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: fixed.. by mistake " string added at the end of com.mysql.jdbc.Driver